# IIS 6 - Application pool keeps stopping

Tags: iis-6, .net-2.0, application-pool

I am trying to set up a site on a Windows 2003 server running IIS 6. When I start the application, I get "Service Unavailable". I googled this error and most indicated it is an application pool identity issue (wrong user id and password). This is an intranet app and I have a non-expiring user id and password. I tested this user id and password and confirmed it is correct. I also added the user id to IIS-WPG group but it still stops after first request. I disabled Rapid fail Protection in IIS and it doesn't die but it takes a long time to (try to) display the page and then says Page Cannot be Displayed. It does the same thing if I run the application pool under Network Services identity, which is already part of IIS-WPG. I have made sure web application folder has proper ACL.

Is there anything else I can try?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed in event log that I was getting a DCOM error before the application pool stop error.

I did the following:

go to Admin Tools > Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config > IIS Admin Service > Right-Click / Properties

Security Tab - Customize the Launch and Activation Permissions > Edit

Add the Network Service (under which my application pool runs; I removed the custom user id) with Local Launch and Local Activation Permissions.

Now, the application pool does not stop but I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the page" error and no errors in System Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003, only ASP.Net version 1.1 is automatically added. I had to go to "Web Service Extensions" in IIS, under <server_name> and add support for ASP.Net 2 and ASP.Net 4. After that everything worked as expected. This, of course, only applies to the "Page Not Found" or "Page Cannot be displayed" errors. I still had to modify the DCOM setting to stop application pool from stopping.
Prior to this, however, I uninstalled and reinstalled IIS.